# Suggestion about Peltier Efficiency With Current Power Setup

Tags: batteries, wiring, peltier

I am currently using the very arbitrary TES1-4902 to cool water (small amounts) using a 5V 2.4A USB Battery Pack (2 Peltiers TES1-4902, 2 5V 2.4 A USB Battery Packs = 5V 4.8A)

- **Recently, it has come to my attention that a different Peltier setup may be able to increase my efficiency, thus giving me more "bang for my buck".**

The current situation that I am in is that I need to achieve the maximum cooling power to cool small amounts of water as quick as possible; however, I need to reduce power consumption so that instead of buying two 5v 2.4A USB battery packs I can buy 1, 3.4 A USB battery pack to support my project and thus reduce my price.

**I know that the more power you put into a peltier, the cooler it gets, so less power is counter-intuitive: so I will split my question into two parts:**

- 1) Is there a more efficient Peltier (where the rated IMAX/VMAX/DT is more efficient than what I have) that runs on a **5V 2.4A batterry**, that takes into account more power is needed to start the Peltier than to run it continuously?

  - How about a 5v 4.8A  battery?
- 2) Using a 3.4 AMP, 5V USB Battery pack, is there any way I can achieve a similar cooling effect than what I currently have (TES1-4902, 5V 4.8A (2 of them)? by using a more efficient peltier?

Thank you so much, while someone answers me I am learning how to read data sheets more efficiently; however, so many of you are much more knowledgeable than me I thought it may be useful to ask you guys who have been so helpful in the past.

Thanks!!!